# from stalk to open neighborhood

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes

We know a morphism between sheaf is isomorphic iff the induced morphism of stalks is isomorphic at every point.

- My question is: if $\alpha :\mathcal{F}\rightarrow \mathcal{F}$, if there exists a point $p$ such that the induced morphism of stalks at $p$ is isomorphic (identity, respectively), is there exists a neighborhood ${U}$ of $p$, such that $\alpha \mid_{U}:\mathcal{F}\mid_{U}\rightarrow \mathcal{F}\mid_{U} $ is isomorphic (identity)?
- If not, what additional condition do we need to have this property?

Comment: If $\mathcal{F}$ is coherent, this is correct.

Comment: @Mohan  you are right，it is true if $\mathcal{F}$ is a coherent sheaf.we use that an epimorphism between f.g.  module is isomorphism. Is there some sufficient and necessary conditions? Or some weak condition? Coherent sheaf maybe too strong.

Comment: In general, I do not think coherence can be dropped.

Comment: The map $\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Q$ is an isomorphism at the generic point but at no other point. In particular it is not an isomorphism on any open set.

Comment: @MooS $O_{SpecZ} \rightarrow f_*O_{SpecQ} $is a good example.

Comment: Yes, you repeated it. The question is clearly local, so it is just commutative algebra. There is no need to sheafifiy the problem